How do I determine the order of ROS messages in Python
I am using ros-noetic. I am receiving ROS messages and putting them into a python Queue which is FIFO. I suspect but I am not sure that what is happening is the subscriber callbacks are called in a multi-threaded fashion, then messages go into the queue out of order with respect to time. As a result I am getting a ROSTimeMovedBackwardsException; which is my core problem. How do I get the ROS time values? I did a dir() on the ROS messages in the callback function to see the attributes and I noticed they have the __gt__(), __lt__(), etc. magic methods. Is that how ROS compares ROS time values on a ROS message? If so could I use a PriorityQueue? I am thinking that may still not solve my problem. Any ideas on how to solve this or at least troubleshoot it? I am not using custom messages.

Please try to create a concrete example of your problem. This sounds like an XY problem. https://xyproblem.info/ The order of messages in your queue will not result in an exception, such as that. You sound be debugging you time sources to find out more about the cause of the exception. Are you using simulation or log playback? Or is your system time changing?

Yes, I knew I was ahead of myself when I posted the issue; but I am new to ROS and I did not know how to troubleshoot it. I just made an assumption because I did not know where else to look and I am not on site to troubleshoot it either. They are actually trying to control a real robot. Sorry I can not give you more details. If/when I go on site what exactly should I be looking for?

Are you trying to debug remotely based on a rosbag that was recorded on the live system?

The most common sources of time in ROS are simulators or rosbag playbacks. If you can describe your system that would help.  https://wiki.ros.org/Clock#Using_Simulation_Time_from_the_.2Fclock_Topic

I am creating a bridge that sends ROS traffic to another network.

When they are using their system they are controlling an actual robot. When they are complete (after the exception is thrown) they send me a bag file which I test on my machine. When I test using the bag file, on my system I do not see the error. Perhaps asking them to run the bag file on their system after they create it will help me narrow down the problem. If it does not work for them, I can infer from that there is something wrong with their system not my code. Then I could take a trip to their location and try to troubleshoot their system.

You'll want to find out about anything publishing '/clock' as a source of time on the system.
